# flume sink metric connection_failed_count

Tags: flume

I turned on the flume metrics with the following variables
-Dflume.monitoring.type=HTTP -Dflume.monitoring.por=12345

I am extracting the metrics via the REST interface using the curl command. I noticed that few weeks ago the connectionFailedCount value was 1294 but today it is 237. However, the ConnectionCreatedCount value did not decrease (or reset).

How to make sense of this observation?

What is the max value of the connectionFailedCount and when does it reset?